# I have initialized app but still its throwing error(Flask)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "nothingggg"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///posts.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


login_manager = LoginManager
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
```

`

The error i am getting is init_app() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'
Can anyone solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a silly one, You forgot the parentheses, So the LoginManager class won't construct

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
```